# How to use Material Components Web Foundations

Tags: javascript, html, material-components-web

Using Material Components, I am trying to figure out how to use the methods of the Foundations of the components.

For an example, I have

```
<div role="progressbar" class="mdc-linear-progress">
  <div class="mdc-linear-progress__buffering-dots"></div>
  <div class="mdc-linear-progress__buffer"></div>
  <div class="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__primary-bar">
    <span class="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__secondary-bar">
    <span class="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my JS I have

```
const bar = $('.mdc-linear-progress')[0];

const MDCLinearProgress = mdc.linearProgress.MDCLinearProgress;
const MDCLinearProgressFoundation = mdc.linearProgress.MDCLinearProgressFoundation;

const progress = new MDCLinearProgress(bar);
const progressFoundation = new MDCLinearProgressFoundation(bar);

progressFoundation.setProgress(0.5);
```

as you can see my goal is trying to use methods like `setProgress` from the `MDCLinearProgressFoundation` class. Though this isn't working and I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong as it gives no error either.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/ErraticFox/pen/LdwYxb

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, on MDCLinearProgress, the set progress method is a property setter (which is a function which is invoked when a given property is written to).  As such, it isn't called as a function, but like so (where myDiv is a pointer to the div tree you created in your question):

```
var mlp = new mdc.linearProgress.MDCLinearProgress(myDiv);
mlp.progress = 0.5;
```

Hope this helps!