# How to generate material-components-web css theme without using npm?

Tags: spring-boot, material-design, thymeleaf, material-components, material-components-web

I'm building a page using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and I want to use material components for web UI. So far everything is okay using the CDN.

```
<head>
<title th:text="${page?.name}">Temporary Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<!-- Required styles for MDC Web -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.css">

<!-- Required MDC Web JavaScript library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
</head>
```

However, I wish to personalize the theme colors. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850184/how-to-use-material-components-web-foundations), but it seems to use the npm.

Are there any other way to generate the theme css files without npm?

Answer (score 0):

The material-components-web css uses custom properties for all colors. All of them default to some color, but you can easily overwrite those defaults like this:

```html
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <style>
    :root {
      --mdc-theme-primary: #ff0000;
      // ...
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Be aware that there's a whole bunch of properties to set. For example, if changing the primary color like in the code above, there's also properties for the desired foreground color on primary background and so on.

For a list of custom properties you can set refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/theming.md#step-4-changing-the-theme-with-css-custom-properties).